# Error reaching my new domain - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: dns, devops

I'm setting up a new site 'slopdonkey.com' and have purchased the domain and pointed it at my DNS (Dreamhost), a fairly straightforward process that I have done a number of times successfully in the past. This time however, I can see that the DNS has propagated but instead of taking me to the standard Dreamhost no content page I get an error saying:

This site can't be reached
slopdonkey.com refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I've cleared my cache, I've changed hosting providers and left over night to see if it was timing issue - none of which have worked for me. Interestingly the support team at Namecheap sent me a screen shot of what I should be seeing this morning when helping to trouble shoot the problem - so there doesn't seem to be a problem on their end - but obviously I still can't see on my own computer when visiting the URL. I've also tried my other laptop and phone to make sure it wasn't something unique to my macbook.

Any help much appreciated?

Nick.

[Proxy settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slxAa.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a proxy issue on your system. You can perform the following for the same.

If you are using the chrome, you should go to the settings >>> change proxy setting >>> It will open the Internet properties >>> Go to connection >>> LAN Settings >>> Tick on Automatically detect to select setting and untick the proxy server option and then click on Ok button.

You should also go to the Ipv4 setting properties page and change to obtain IP Address directly instead of static IP Address.

The issue should be resolve with this.

Comment: Hi, it opened the below box - what should I select / unselect?

Comment: sorry here is Snip20161018_1.png

Comment: Sorry again, i've included link to the image in original question - many thanks!

Comment: It should work with the settings as per the attached file also choose the DHCP while connecting to the internet.

Comment: Thanks v. much @Herrick.P will give it a go